# What do you call a disease with an unknown cure?

Tags: single-word-requests

We call a disorder with an unknown cause or [etiology](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/aetiology?q=etiology) as *[idiopathic](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/idiopathic)*. But what about a disease with an unknown cure — is there a single-word adjective (or phrase) that captures both the current unknowability and future possibility of a cure?

I am specifically trying to avoid "incurable" and its synonyms, as it precludes the possibility of a future medical breakthrough that would render its object preventable or curable.

Comment: There's a semantic problem here: it isn't clear that every disease has a cure; thus, one can't logically say "a disease with an unknown cure" because it presumes that there's a cure we don't know yet. That isn't even "optimistic", it's presumptuous. The disease is **currently incurable**, as starwed says. That's optimistic because it implies that some day there will be a cure. As jwpat7 says, there're diseases & conditions that're intrinsically incurable because they're beyond the pale of reversibility. Etiology assumes a cause + effect, but disease doesn't assume a cure, emotion does.

Comment: @BillFranke We physicians very often feel there will be a cure for a disease we don't currently know how to cure. It's unquestionably optimistic, and not even slightly presumptuous. Don't forget, the disease _always_ appears before the cure. (Yes, it's possible for a treatment to exist prior to the appearance of a disease which it then cures, but logically it was not the cure until the disease came into being, so I reiterate, no "cure" _can_ exist before its disease.) We often see scientific research working towards a cure, so expecting a cure for a currently incurable disease is common.

Comment: @JohnM: My point was semantic: "a disease with an unknown cure" is presumptuous because it begs the question (logical fallacy). "The disease is currently incurable" is optimistic (not presumptuous) because it implies the possibility of a future cure ("but we're working on one & hope to have one soon"). "We physicians very often feel there will be a cure for a disease we don't currently know how to cure" is emotion (hope) talking, not logic or reason. Nothing wrong with "hope" except that hopes aren't always met. "Cures" sometimes lead to the evolution of refractory pathogenic bacteria.

Comment: @BillFranke Bill, it's not emotion speaking. It's demonstrably not. ALL human disease were once incurable, yet we have now cured thousands of them. That's science. We continue to cure more every day. And I reiterate, if you pay attention to directed scientific research, you can very often see specific progress being made towards specific cures, and then you see the cures appear. That's not emotion, Bill. If there's any illogic at work here, it's the sensationalistic misapplication of data in your last sentence. And by the way, you used "beg the question" incorrectly. Look it up.

Comment: @JohnM: It's used correctly: _We've found cures for thousands of once incurable diseases. X is a currently incurable disease. Ergo, we'll also find a cure for X_. The initial premise is false: there's no such thing as an incurable disease that's been cured. There were & are only **currently incurable diseases**. If Socrates doesn't die, he's neither mortal nor a man. The conclusion's untenable & false. Some currently incurable diseases may never be cured simply because there's no cure. Assuming there's a cure is faith. Faith is emotion, not science. MRSA's an example of a refractory bacterium.

Comment: And now for something completely different.  What's an incurable disease called?  It's called, "You gonna die!"

Comment: @rhetorician not all incurable diseases can/will kill you.

Comment: @BillFranke Stimulating argumentation, and thank you!! 1. Saying a "cure" leads to MRSA  is off the mark; the cause is the excessive use of antibiotics, & it's "resistant," not "refractory." 2. Rather than point out all the holes in your ALMOST plausible logic, I'll merely say you can't use "once incurable" in premise one, and then call it false by misconstruing it with "incurable." Further: A lot of the debate here has been predicated on an erroneous implication in the meaning of incurable. It means "does not have a cure." It does NOT mean cannot or will not.

Comment: @JohnM: There can be no discussion when the discussants don't agree on what they're discussing. No one can win a debate when the definition of the primary word being debated, _incurable_, is in dispute. Your arguments are pointless, as are mine, if we can't agree on something to discuss. We haven't done so. That reduces the discussion to an adult playground version of "I'm right & you're wrong", "No, I'm right & you're wrong". End of what was never a discussion in the first place. BTW, antibiotics are cures for bacterial infections. They're overused because they exist. Ergo, the cure => MRSA.

Comment: @BillFranke Well, gee, Bill, I thought it was a discussion. And I was enjoying it. I thought you were, too. Honestly, I like to be challenged, and I particularly like to have someone convince me of their opinion. And you're close to doing that. e.g. I see your point about cures causing problems; I merely think it's a bit of misdirection to say things like "they're overused because they exist." Not much causality in there. And I would say we agree wholeheartedly on a crucial matter, namely that the meaning of incurable is in dispute. And yet, we didn't really get focused on that. Agreed again.

Comment: @JohnM.: Here's an [interesting article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-21783945): _Early HIV drugs 'functionally cure about one in 10'_. This illustrates my point about the need for a qualifier before _incurable_: (M-W3UD) "1 : **impossible to cure** (an _incurable_ disease)
2 : admitting of no remedy or correction (_incurable_ optimism) : being a thing specified beyond any possibility of alteration or control (these _incurable_ busybodies)." Optimists add _currently_, pessimists add _eternally_, and eunuchs add nothing.

Comment: @BillFranke I can't say only LOL, because comments are required to be longer. But, LOL. :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> I am specifically trying to avoid "incurable" and its synonyms, as it precludes the possibility of a future medical breakthrough that would render its object preventable or curable.

That would render this category of words useless, since this can never be precluded.

It's ok to say incurable -- it's understood that there's an implicit "currently" riding with the word, since no disease can be *intrinsically* incurable.

Comment: I disagree that “no disease can be intrinsically incurable”.  For example, various kinds of [dementia](http://www.alzheimersreadingroom.com/2009/09/dementia-and-eight-types-of-dementia.html) cannot be cured: brain function is irreversibly damaged by 
frontotemporal and vascular dementia.  Some brain tumors also destroy parts of the brain irreversibly, and some heart disease damages the heart irreversibly.  Some of these conditions can be ameliorated, but since they can't be reversed they can't be cured.

Comment: @jwpat7 That's what people used to believe about a plethora of diseases and conditions a few decades ago. [Clarke's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke's_three_laws) are worth a mention here.

Comment: @coleopterist, “Clarke's laws” are not laws in the same sense as [laws of thermodynamics](http://www.ridgenet.net/~do_while/sage/v7i1f.htm), and to believe otherwise is akin to superstition.  If disease destroys all the bits of the brain that carry some particular memories, and if those memories have not been redundantly stored elsewhere, then those memories are gone.  Also see notes about Third Law of Thermodynamics at above link:  “Since 100% efficiency is impossible, it means that there are no truly reversible processes. That, in turn, means that all processes are irreversible.”

Comment: @jwpat7 ... and by that reasoning, nothing is curable. There are _complete_ cures and _partial_ cures. In your example of cerebral atrophy, if the degeneration is stopped and the cells regenerated, thereby allowing the patient to make new memories, then that is considered a cure, albeit not a complete one. If a patient who has lost both his arms and legs and is fitted with _perfect_ prosthetics, some would still not call it a complete "cure", although it would be, in my books.

Comment: @jwpat7 I would distinguish between a disease, and the damage *caused* by the disease.  Also, the laws of thermodynamics do not truly speak to such a situation, because we're not discussing an isolated system.  (It is often much *harder* to reverse a process, but that doesn't speak to its absolute impossibility.)

Comment: @jwpat7 If cancer damages your brain, and then you cure the cancer completely, you have cured the *disease*. The damage caused by the cancer can never be cured--just *healed*. If you got a limb amputated, you wouldn't talk about "curing my amputation" or "curing the doctor who amputated my limb" or even "curing the gangrene that forced them to remove my limb." It is common to say "cured him of x disease *and reversed all its effects." A cure should never be taken to imply complete reversal.

Answer (score 14):

I agree with @starwed's answer. But you can perhaps consider the following terms which may provide the nuance that you are looking for:

> 1. [Remediless](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/remediless): Not having a remedy; not capable of being remedied.
> 2. [Irremediable](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/irremediable): impossible to cure or put right
> 3. [Immedicable](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/immedicable): unable to be healed or treated; incurable.

Even though they appear to be synonymous with *incurable*, I've added 2 and 3 simply for the sake of completeness. All three words suggest that there is no drug/remedy/medicine or treatment available for an illness or injury.

Comment: [*Untreatable*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/untreatable) is another word similar to #3 and is especially common in headlines describing antibiotic-resistant illnesses: "untreatable gonorrhea threat rises", "outbreak of virtually untreatable TB", "deadly, untreatable superbugs".

Answer (score 12):

An English Japanese Dictionary of Medical Science at hand (compiled by 18 professors and associate professors of Medical Department of Tohoku University and 8 professors of medical departments and pharmaceutical departments of other universities, and first published by Kenkyusha Publishing in 1999）shows the word, ‘intractable disease’ for a disease with unknown cure among others (obstinacy, refractoriness’, inveterate, obstinate, refractory under the headword, 難病-Nanbyou (disease difficult to cure).

I think ‘intractable’ is closest to the disease you’re referring to. In Japan we have a governmental research institute called ‘Intractable Disease Information Center’ who centrally collects, controls, and supplies information of all kinds of intractable disease to medical institutions and specialists.

Comment: I disagree that *intractable* means there is an unknown cure. *Dorland's Medical Dictionary* defines *intractable* as "resistant to cure, relief, or control." The term is usually used when you're trying to treat something, maybe even with a tried and true therapy, and it isn't working. You have probably heard the phrase "intractable pain." As for *refractory*, it is also defined as "being resistant to treatment." These words don't imply anything about a cure.

Comment: I disagree with JLG. I think *intractable* is an excellent choice for this context.

Comment: While the OP's _incurable_ "precludes the possibility of a future medical breakthrough", _intractable_ presumes the availability of an existing cure. 難病- appears to be used in the same sense as _chronic_ or _rare_ disease or disorder.

Answer (score 3):

Although I think starwed comes very close to answering Sel, I'm not entirely certain that the essence of Sel's question has been truly addressed in all of the fascinating discussion that has gone on here. What Sel wants is a word that specifically states that the disease has no cure at this time, but also that it is likely to be cured at some future time.

In response, starwed points out that "incurable" does not preclude a future cure, and I think this is right, but if I am not mistaken, Sel wants something more. What seems to be wanted is a stronger implication within the desired word that although the disease does not have a cure, *a cure is expected*.

If I am correct about this, then I have to say to Sel, in my 36 years of experience in medicine, I have never encountered such a word. That doesn't prove such a word doesn't exist, but I'd bet quite a lot on its nonexistence.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this called a *disease with no known cure*.

Comment: Well, that makes sense on every level: it doesn't imply that it's curable but that there's an unknown cure waiting for someone to discover it, and it doesn't imply that it's incurable. It's quite neutral, which is as it should be.

Answer (score 2):

The etymology for *idiopathic* does not indicate “the cause of this symptom is unknown” so much as “the cause is unique to this case”, *i.e.*, it is not related to other (otherwise known) causes for this symptom. (See http://thefreedictionary.com/idio-.) If someone finds a synonym for *incurable* more to your liking, it therefore will not have the same form as *idiopathic*.

(Now if you’d ask for a word for a cure that worked, for unknown reason, only for one patient, a nonce-word beginning with *idio-* might be constructed; *idioiatric*, perhaps.)

Answer (score 1):

As academical reference there is an adjective in Greek language *a-n-iatos* where *a-* = has negative meaning (so like “non-”), the *n* is there only for making the word easy to pronounce, and *iatos* which derives from the noun *iasis* = healing.

Normally this word is being used for diseases that they can not be entirely cured, such as diabetes or Parkinson’s disease.

Answer (score 1):

I believe **"terminal illness"** is the word you are looking for.

According to Wikipedia (although not reliable, it is great for quick answers), a "terminal illness" is "a medical term popularized in the 20th century to describe a disease that cannot be cured or adequately treated and that is reasonably expected to result in the death of the patient within a short period of time."

This seems to be the closest word with the definition that you are looking for.

Comment: An **incurable** disease does not have to be **terminal**. There are lots of diseases which can't be cured, but which don't usually kill you.

Answer (score 0):

"There isn't a definite cure for the disease" can be used instead.

Comment: Does that mean that there's an _indefinite_ cure or a _tentative_ cure? How about just "There's no known cure"? That takes care of all the semantic problems. Or "Currently, there's no known cure, but there may be one day"? = Verbose version.